# Which essential amino acids are the most likely to be deficient in a vegan diet?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, protein

Beside total proteins and the need for protein combining (see [this question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/62/115)), here I ask a more specific question regarding **single amino-acids**: what are the most likely essential amino acids to be deficient in a vegan diet? Where to find them?

Answer (score 5):

An [answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/1131/120) has been given on the [Health Stack Exchange](https://health.stackexchange.com/):

> A vegan diet is based only on vegetal foods. If we analyze the amino
>   acid content of different food protein sources (animal and plant
>   proteins),  **lysine** is consistently at a much lower concentration
>   in all major plant-food protein groups than in animal foods ([1](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/1131/120),
>   [2](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/59/5/1203S.short)). Lysine is one of the essential amino acids, thus lysine is most
>   likely to be the first limiting amino acid in diets that are based
>   predominantly on cereal grains ([2](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/59/5/1203S.short)).
>
> For this reason the American Dietetic Association, in its 2009
>   position paper on vegetarian diets, recommends an increase of
>   consumption of **beans and soy products** in order to satisfy the
>   essential amino acids requirements in vegan diets ([3](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19562864)).

Answer (score 2):

This quote from a recent [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6893534/) responds your question very clearly:

> Amino acid intakes are sufficient and lysine intake might only be limiting in vegan individuals who have a low protein intake when basing their diet on a very limited and monotonous pattern where the protein intake would only come from, for example, grains alone—an unrealistic situation in developed countries.

I would like to point to my [answer](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/486/what-bean-provides-the-best-source-of-essential-amino-acids/2633#2633) to a related question, to highlight methionine as a potential deficient amino acids in certain diets. This [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0306987708003836?via%3Dihub) discusses how high glycine in vegan diets may lower bio-availability of methionine, but at the same time, lower methionine levels seem beneficial.

I would also point to this interesting result by another [study](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00394-021-02790-y) assessing the diet of 36 vegans, mentioning:

> The present study also showed that the lower dietary intake of AAs in vegans was hardly reflected in the plasma concentrations of free AAs.

However, the latter study also mentions a tendency for lower intake of lysine by vegans (also of methionine, but to a much lower extent), which may seem to contradict the first statement of this answer.

To recap, I think I showed there is some controversy and the results of the scientific inquiries into vegan diets may vary. Also, important, intake deficiency does not translate into serum level deficiency. A balanced vegan diet (beans, grains, legumes) should not be lacking any essential amino acids. An unbalanced one (e.g. grain-based) could be lacking in lysine (perhaps methionine, in special cases, e.g. no soy intake), so I would bet on lysine for 'the most likely deficient amino acid in vegan diets'. To find it, it takes just to only eat a variety of vegan products.